# Add and subtract values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Need Help with following piece of jQuery code;

What I'm trying to do is;

1. add Amount into Total
2. when amount added Checkbox value get double
3. If checkbox state change, checkbox Updated value minus or add into Total accordingly
4. if Amount minus from Total, checkbox value change back to original
5. If checkbox state change, checkbox Updated value minus or add into Total accordingly

Following is the piece of jQuery Code

```
$('#Addcar').on('click', function() {
if($(this).html()=='Add') {
    $(this).html('Remove');
    var tot = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) + parseFloat($('#QuoteAmount').val());
    var totcan = parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val()) + 2;
    $('#TotalPrice').val(tot);
    $('#Cancelation').val(totcan);
} else {
    $(this).html('Add');
    var tot = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) - parseFloat($('#QuoteAmount').val());
    var totcan = parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val()) - 2;
    $('#TotalPrice').val(tot);
    $('#Cancelation').val(totcan);
}
});

$('#Cancelation').change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) + Number($(this).val());
} else {
    total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) - Number($(this).val());
}
$('#TotalPrice').val(total);
});
```

Here is the fiddle which explains better;

**Updated Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/55n8acus/7/

If QuoteAmount value added and checkbox value remove from Total and then remove QuoteAmount value , the result value will be wrong, it should be 52 not 48, the reason checkbox won't update and it still remove 4 from Total instead it should remove 2.

Thanks for all the help

Regards.

Comment: And whats the problem ?

Comment: values not added or minus accordingly.

Comment: Just clicking the button in the fiddle, it seems to work for me ?

Comment: if add, total is 102 and if checkbox uncheck total value change to 48 but it should change to 98.

Comment: @shehary It's 48 because you subtract ("TotalAmount" - `checkbox value`), which is (52 - 4) = 48. Maybe you want to subtract (**TotalPrice** - `checkbox value`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can understand from the question is that you want to subtract the value from total price, but you are accidentally using **#TotalValue** instead of **#TotalPrice** when you click on the checkbox, change the code to this, it will work as expected.

```
$('#Cancelation').change(function(){
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) + Number($(this).val());
} else {
    total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) - Number($(this).val());
}
$('#TotalPrice').val(total);
});
```

here is the updated js fiddle :- [jsfiddle.net/55n8acus/8](https://jsfiddle.net/55n8acus/8)

```js
$('#Addcar').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).html()=='Add') {
        $(this).html('Remove');
        var tot = parseFloat($('#TotalAmount').val()) + parseFloat($('#QuoteAmount').val());
        var totcan = parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val()) + 2;
        if(!$("#Cancelation").is(':checked')){
            tot = tot -4;
        }
        $('#TotalPrice').val(tot);
        $('#Cancelation').val(totcan);
        $('#Cancel').html(totcan);        
    } else {
        $(this).html('Add');
        var tot = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) - parseFloat($('#QuoteAmount').val());
        if(!$("#Cancelation").is(':checked')){
            tot +=2;
        }
        var totcan = parseFloat($('#Cancelation').val()) - 2;
        $('#TotalPrice').val(tot);
        $('#Cancelation').val(totcan);
        $('#Cancel').html(totcan);
    }
});

$('#Cancelation').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) + Number($(this).val());
    } else {
        total = parseFloat($('#TotalPrice').val()) - Number($(this).val());
    }
    $('#TotalPrice').val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="Addcar">Add</a><br>
<input type="text" id="QuoteAmount" value="50" />
<input type="text" name="TotalAmount" id="TotalAmount" value="52" /><br>
<input type="text" name="TotalPrice" id="TotalPrice" value="0" /><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Cancelation" value="2" checked> <span id="Cancel">2</span>
```

Comment: Thanks alot but it wont reslove the complete problem, please check updated fiddle and note at bottom of question, regards and thanks again.

Comment: What is it that you exactly intend to do? I am unable to grasp the point of the program. There is a logical issue with the problem, and I cannot really help with the exact logic unless I understand what you are looking for

Comment: lemme explain, I have Quote value which is 50 and another value which is 52( it already has the value of check box added which is 2) its Total Amount Value, Now if I add Quote Value again in Total Price(not in Total Amount) so it will be 102 and checkbox value get double to 4 so if i want i can minus the check box value 4 from Total 102, lets say i minus the value 4 and then i decide to remove the Quote Value to, i should get the orginal old value which was 52 not 48, hope I be able to explain it properly

Comment: It should get you 52-2 = 50 right, since the checkbox is unchecked?

Comment: no it should get 52, see 50 is Quote and TotalAmount is 52, it already contain the checkbox value 2.

Comment: If I uncheck the checkbox when totalAmount=52, then the totalAmount is supposed to remain unchanged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79825/discussion-between-namit-singal-and-shehary).